# regular expression "(?<!^)(?=[A-Z])"

Tags: c#, regex

I spent like three hours trying to understant how does `"(?<!^)(?=[A-Z])"` works to split at tring according to capital letters i.e.

```
string[] s = Regex.Split("TheWorldWithoutStrangers", "(?<!^)(?=[A-Z])");
```

How does it work !! I do understand what is the meaning of each char in the above expression, but I do not get how does it work together. why `"(? < !^)([A-Z])"` doesnot work ? it means that whenever you find a captial letter that is not after a new line, then split, am I right ?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Read about regex [Lookbehind and Lookahead](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9099/The-30-Minute-Regex-Tutorial).

Comment: I want array s to have the values
{The,
World,
Without,
Strangers}

Comment: Must you do it with Regex? I would think a solution you understand will be better than a solution that does magic, any day. Either read Lookbehind and Lookahead, or do it with a simple loop and so.

Comment: i am trying to understand  regular expressions, I know how to do it other ways

Comment: Three whole hours? Did you experiment, and tried to remove parts of the pattern? For example, what did `"(?=[A-Z])"` do for you? How about just `[A-Z]`? Did you try to *match* for either of them?

Comment: @Lev - it is working for me on http://www.pythonregex.com/ . If lookbehind is the problem (like in JavaScript), `(?!^)(?=[A-Z])` should work the same.

Comment: @Kobi it works the same in the sense that both don't work in my Python interpreter. I do `re.split('(?<!^)(?=[A-Z])', "TheWorldWithoutStrangers")` and the same without `<`. It just doesn't seem to work, although it matches.

Comment: @Lev: That's a peculiarity of Python's `split`: it won't work with a regex that doesn't consume any characters (or, as it says in the [Python docs](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#module-contents), on "an empty pattern match").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key here is that the two parts `(?<!...)` and `(?=...)` are zero-width assertions. The first one makes sure `^` (start of string) does not occur right before the match position and the second one ensures that `[A-Z]` (single capital letter) appears right after the match position. The actual match is empty because neither of the assertions actually match any characters. The entire expression merely matches a position.

Answer (score 5):

The `^` means the beginning of a line, and `(?<!...)` is a negative look behind, so `(?<!^)` matches any position in the string that is not right at the beginning of the line.

The set `[A-Z]` matchies any capital letter, and `(?=...)` is a positive look ahead, so `(?=[A-Z])` matches any position in the string that is right before a capital letter.

Put them together, and the expression matches any position in the string that is not right at the beginning of a line, and that is right before a capital letter.

Comment: You must make sure that nothing in the regex actually matches a substring in your string because the matching part is removed from the output.

Comment: @imad: That would include the capital letter in the match. Using only a look behind and look ahead makes the expression match the position between the capital letter and the character before that. As the match is zero length the split won't remove anything from the string, and the result has all the characters from the original string.