# How to split string preserving spaces and any number of \n characters

Tags: c#, regex

I want to split the string and create a collection, with the following rules:
The string should be splitted into words.

1) If the string contains '\n' it should be considered as a seperate '\n' word.
2) If the string contains more than one '\n' it should considered it as more than on '\n' words.
3) No space should be removed from the string. Only exception is, if space comes between two \n it can be ignored.

PS: I tried a lot with string split, first split-ted \n characters and created a collection, downside is, if I have two \n consecutively, I'm unable to create two dummy words into the collection. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Is there anyway to do this using regex?

Comment: Have you tried Regex.Split? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8yttk7sy.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split with a regex like this:

```
(?<=[\S\n])(?=\s)
```

Something like:

```
var substrings = Regex.Split(input, @"(?<=[\S\n])(?=\s)");
```

This will not remove any spaces at all, but that was not required so should be fine.

If you really want the spaces between `\n`s to be removed, you could split with something like:

```
(?<=[\S\n])(?=\s)(?:[ \t]+(?=\n))?
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like homework. As such, [read up on `\b`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html).

Should set you in the right direction.

Comment: That probably won't work as it detects `\S`->`\s` and `\s`->`\S` (of which only either is wanted), but not `\s`->`\n` or `\n`->`\s`.

Comment: @Wormbo, this was provided merely to get the OP started. There is no regex, magic bullet for the OP's spec. As such, `\b` (word boundary) is arguably the single best starting point.

Comment: True, but there's quite a jump from knowing a predefined construct for word boundaries and knowing the more basic constructs to build it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Read up on the [zero-width assertions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx#grouping_constructs). With them you can define a split position between e.g. `\s` and `\S` without actually matching either adjacent character.

*edit:*
Here's [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10869547/regular-expression-a-z) where the OP asked about those constructs.